# Calculating a double transactionfee for multiple parties

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

This is probably mind-numbingly easy for some of you but I have trouble figuring this one out.

Here's the situation:

A company called `A` sells a product to an individual called `B`.

`C`, another company who hooked up `A` and `B` looks at this transaction and takes a certain `%` from this

`D`, the one who eventually handles the payment looks at the transaction between `A` & `B`, adds what `C` wants to take and then takes a certain `%` for themselves.

What would the calculation be for the transaction so that `A` gets the money they asked for, `C` gets the `%` they desire, `D` can take a `%` without regard for all parties and `B` has to pay for the costs `C and D` as well.

Any starting points as to how I can figure this one out?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 1):

A wants a price $P$. C takes a certain percentage of that amount for themselves. Now "percentage" literally means "per 100". For example, if C wants $10\%$, they actually want a fraction $\dfrac{10}{100} = \dfrac 1{10}$ of the price.

Let $r$ be the ratio (percentage over 100) that C wants. The amount of money that C wants is this ratio times the price $P$. That is $rP$. Therefore, if D were not around, then B would have to pay $P$ to A and $rP$ to C. So they would have to pay out $P + rP = (1 + r)P$ in total.

But D wants their blood money too. Just as with C, the percentage D wants is actually a ratio, obtained by dividing the percentage by 100. Call that ratio $R$. But this ratio is not of $P$, but of the amount that A and C receive together, $(1+r)P$. So D wants $R(1+r)P$ for themselves.

Now B must dig deeper into their wallet and come up with not just the $(1 + r)P$ needed to pay off A and C, but also the $R(1+r)P$, or $(1+r)P + R(1+r)P = (1+R)(1+r)P$ in total.

The pattern continues like this. If E figures he can spot a sucker here, and demands an additional ratio $\rho$ of the total payment to A, C, D. Then B would be stuck paying out $(1 + \rho)(1 + R)(1 + r)P$.